# How to feed android apps fake camera data?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I want to have a background service that, when turned on, would feed any app that uses the camera a bitmap that I would set. Is that at all doable in android? Where would I start to look for that?

Comment: Not for a normal SDK application. You could do it through a custom version of the OS.

Comment: What's your underlying purpose? Testing? Augmented Reality? a Joke app? The more you're willing to tell us, the more we can help you.